# Entity Linking and Recognition

Tags: nltk, spacy, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition, conversational-ai

I'm trying to build an entity recognition model using Spacy and that links any recognized set of entities to documents in the database.

My holdup for now is that I haven't found a good way of integrating the Sentiment analysis I'm to use with my model.
Do I really need a sentiment analysis?

All suggestions are welcome!!!

Comment: Why are you asking us if you need sentiment analysis? Why are you having trouble integrating it?

Comment: You should show few lines of code.

Comment: It's not as much as about the code. It's about the next steps to take.

Comment: @polm23, here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: https://ibb.co/1Txjy6v

Comment: Hello Pius, it sounds like maybe a teacher/client has told you to use sentiment analysis, but you are not clear why? In which case, discuss it with them? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how you can ask a question that will be easier for people to answer.